# HashSet<List<Integer>> time complexity

Tags: java, hash

I know `HashSet` has both lookup/add time complexity of **O(1)**. But I was worried if it has the same time complexity if the `Set` holds `List`, for me it's hard to believe it would only takes O(1), how would we do hash on a List?

Thanks

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your title, as complexity for `Set` is unspecified while `HashSet` specifies it.

Answer (score 2):

`hashCode` of `List`s (for example, see the implementation of `AbstractList`) is a function of all the elements of the `List`. The same is true for the `equals` implementation.

Therefore lookup/add in a `Set<List<SomeType>>` will take `O(k)` where `k` is the size of the `List` you are looking for/adding. However, since `k` doesn't depend on the number of elements in the `Set`, the lookup time would still be a constant function of the number of elements of the `Set`, so you can still say lookup takes `O(1)`, since the running time of lookup/add in a `Collection` is calculated as a function of the number of elements in the `Collection`, not the size of individual elements.

Comment: @Joey You may consider k a constant if you only consider the largest list present in the Set at a given time. However, you can always add larger Lists to the Set (or search for larger Lists not present in the Set), so k doesn't remain constant (unless you know in advance that you will only lookup/add Lists bound by a constant number of elements).

Comment: that's actually a good point. I retract my statements and start screaming the opposite now ;-) My argument only held for an immutable set, I guess. Thus `HashSet` effectively assumes `hashCode` to be O(1) to arrive at its O(1) metric. To be honest, having `List.equals` and `hashCode` act in that way, as well as having no equivalent of `IEqualityComparer` in Java is a fairly big flaw in the collections API in my eyes. Though something that cannot be rectified anymore now.

Comment: However, disregarding O(k) because k doesn't depend on the number of items in the set is still not right. O(max L) with L being the set of list lengths in the set might be technically more correct. And we'd even have to multiply that by the complexity of `hashCode` again, in case we have a `HashSet<List<List<Integer>>>` ...